# Label is not updating after being appended

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, append

The following code is opening a jQuery dialog.
I wish to move one of the labels (id as *EventTime*) close to the dialog buttons, at the bottom.

The code:

```
$("#FireAlert").dialog("open");
$(".ui-dialog-buttonpane").append($("#EventTime"));
function pad(val) {
    return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val;
}
eventTimer = setInterval(function () {
    $("#EventTime").text("Event time - " + pad(parseInt(eventSeconds / 3600 % 60, 10)) + ":" + pad(parseInt(eventSeconds / 60 % 60, 10)) + ":" + pad(++eventSeconds % 60));
}, 1000);
```

When pausing the timer and inspecting the label, it has the right text, but it is not updating in the browser, i.e. it's still showing the initialized text.

When omitting the *append* command, the label is updating correctly.

Sample here - https://jsfiddle.net/8s9pceg4

Comment: Hard to guess why it does not work. Ran your code and seems fine so what is different?

Comment: Is there more than one $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane") on the page?

Comment: Please see if all your id in html are unique

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: When searching for $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane") only one result is found. The EventTime id is unique across the website. I've added a simple jsfiddle sample,